# Comportamiento inesperado en mi checkbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, mvc

quería saber si me podían ayudar con este tema que, para mi, es 100% visual.

Lo que tengo es un checkbox que selecciona Todos los demás inputs, que hasta ahi funciona bien, el tema es cuando yo cambio de vista, y vuelvo a la del checkbox, éste aunque tenga valor true o false, siempre se va a poner como si estuviese en true.

Adjunto imágenes (final de todo):

IMAGEN 1: CHECKBOX ON, ESTADO: TRUE

IMAGEN 2: CHECKBOX ON, ESTADO: FALSE

Códigos:

CHECKBOX:

```
<p>
        <label class="switch pull-right">
            <input name="SeleccionarTodos" type="checkbox" id="SeleccionarTodos" onclick="checkAll()" />
            <span class="slider round vista"></span>
        </label>
</p>
```

Como lo estoy guardando:

```
var checkStatus = $('#SeleccionarTodos').prop('checked');
sessionStorage.setItem("SeleccionarTodos", checkStatus);
```

Como lo estaroy recuperando:

```
 $(document).ready(function () { 
        var sessionStatus = sessionStorage.getItem("SeleccionarTodos");
        console.log(sessionStatus);
            
        $('#SeleccionarTodos').prop('checked', sessionStatus);
}
```

Como ven en la imagen, este `console.log()` me dice el valor de la propiedad 'checked'

```
console.log(sessionStatus);
```

[image: IMAGEN 1]

[image: IMAGEN 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece ser que el problema es porque `sessionStorage` guarda toda la información como cadena y, aunque en la consola veas `false`, no se trata de un valor booleano, sino de un texto.

Entre las curiosidades de Javascript, cuando compara valores no booleanos como booleano, se hace una conversión y solo resulta falso con:

- null o falso
- Cadena vacía
- Arreglo vacío
- Cero
- (Probablemente algún otro que se me escapa)

Entonces, la cadena `'false'`, al no estar vacía, se convierte a verdadero, por lo que solo debes comparar y asignar un valor booleano:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Si no se puede leer, asignar valor por defecto
    let sessionStatus = sessionStorage.getItem("SeleccionarTodos") || false;
    // Asegurar que es un valor booleano
    if(sessionStatus === 'true') {
        sessionStatus = true;
    } else {
        sessionStatus = false;
    }
    console.log(sessionStatus);
    $('#SeleccionarTodos').prop('checked', sessionStatus);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación!! Me sirvió de mucho!